# auto-build system with ant

Tags: java, python, ant, build-automation

We have a **python** auto-build system in a C# project. It will do **daily source update and build** automatically and **send email** out if build failed.  Now we are thinking to have a similar system for our **Java** project.

We use **Ant** in this Java project, but not **Log4j**.

It looks like the simple way (for us) is use **python** and call **Ant** to do build, and write result to file, and then paser the result file to see failed or not.

Do you have a better idea?

Comment: If you can consider commercial system, take a look at TeamCity. It works nicely.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend using a continuous integration server such as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org).  It's simple to set up, has Ant integration built-in and will do all the parsing of results and reporting builds as passed or failed for you, plus much, much more.